# Install arangodb service using curl and the http rest api

Tags: arangodb

I have a problem registering a service that's on the filesystem already. I know I managed to do it before but I've lost the skill.

I have tried this:

```
curl
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
  -X POST
  -d @install-data.json 
  http://localhost:8529/_api/foxx
```

**install-data.json**

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "engines": {
            "arangodb": "^3.0.0"
        },
        "main": "index.js"
    },
    "source": "/var/opt/foxx/getting-started.zip"
}
```

The service bundle is located at `/var/opt/foxx/getting-started.zip`

The result is

```
{"error":true,"errorNum":3013,"errorMessage":"failed to parse service options\nDetails: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1","code":400}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the HTTP API when parsing `configuration` and `dependencies` in the request body. Github issue [here](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/3125).
Your given parameters in configuration should also exists in your service `manifest.json` so there is no need to set them in your request. For you it should work if you only post

```
{
  "source": "/var/opt/foxx/getting-started.zip"
}
```

Comment: You're a star! Is it possible to point source to a folder as well? I'm using docker and the files are mounted already.

Comment: The docs says only zip but the code says folder works too :-) I tested it and it works with folders for me. I will change this in the docs.